# Passing json object from one js file to another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a js file X which has a json object in which I want to pass the object to another js file Y and execute according to the values of the object. These two js files are referenced to the same html page.

The json object is something like this

```
var displayDetails = {
    "A" :   {
                data : "1",
                display : "A1"
        },
    "B" :   {
                data : "2",
                display : "B2"
        }
};
```

After which the json object was parsed

```
var cachedOptions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(displayDetails));
```

All this are in js file X. So how do I access that cachedOptions or displayDetails on js B? I am new to json so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: They should both be able to access each other's variables if the variables are in global scope. You're going to need to post your code. If in one file you declare a variable e.g. var displayDetails; then the other should be able to read it, as long as it's reading it after the other has written to it. Your var xyz statement has to be outside of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you aren't using name spacing you can simply refer to a variable in script X that is declared in script Y. The HTML page will compile all the script files listed on the page together so 'global' variables will be able to 'see' each other.

Of course, when writing these files individually the code won't make sense, but it will work in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `global namespace` and attach objects and functions to it so it can be used anywhere in your app.

File X:

```
window.scope = {};
scope.displayDetails = {
    "A" :   {
            data : "1",
            display : "A1"
    },
    "B" :   {
            data : "2",
            display : "B2"
    }
};
scope.cachedOptions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(scope.displayDetails));
```

File Y:

```
/** Use the object from another file. */
console.log(scope.displayDetails.A);

console.log(scope.cachedOptions);
```